# how to send CSRF token using flutter http request

Tags: python, django, flutter, dart, django-rest-framework

how to send CSRF token using flutter HTTP request
I have a Django based project that uses `django-rest-framework` for API, when I send a `POST` request using `Postman` it works perfectly fine,, but when I send an `HTTP.post` request from my flutter application I get this response :

```
Forbidden 403
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
You are seeing this message because this HTTPS site requires a “Referer header” to be sent by your Web browser, but none was sent
```

In django am using `function based view` to receive the requests:

```py
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny,])
@csrf_exempt
def create_user(request):
   ......
   .....
```

then in the `URLS` :

```py
    path("api/v1/create_user/", api.create_user, name="create_user"),
```

and am sending the request in flutter :

```dart
http.post(Uri(myURL),header={
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
}
,body={
'my_key':'my_value',
})
```

Comment: you can pass it on header

Comment: @ArbiterChil where can I even get it from !! how to pass in the header, can please give me some more information?

Comment: just pass the header with the key 'Referer' and the value is any url

Comment: nop, it didn't do any difference, same 403 forbidden response!

Answer (score 2):

When you are creating a HTTPS website using django, you need to use a Referer header.
Assuming your website's domain is `yoursite.com`, you need to set this in your header

```
{"Referer": "https://yoursite.com"}
```

in dart/flutter using [http package](https://pub.dev/packages/http)

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
var resp = http.post(Uri.parse("https://yoursite.com/api/v1/create_user"),
    headers: {"Referer": "https://yoursite.com"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to get a Flutter app to send a CSRF token is possibly the wrong approach. If you're using some sort of token based authentication then the users auth token should be sufficient for the API to trust the request.

Carefully setting the order of the values in the `REST_FRAMEWORK.DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` list may be enough to prevent the request from checking for the CSRF token. It is worth noting that `rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication` is the authentication class that ultimately causes the 403 response.

Try moving whatever authentication class which provides your token auth to the top of the list, for example:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": (
        "oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication",  # <- this at top!
        "rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication",
        "rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication",
    ),
}
```